# Differences between Exception and Error

Tags: java, exception, throwable

I'm trying to learn more about basic Java and the different types of Throwables, can someone let me know the differences between Exceptions and Errors?

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Errors should not be caught or handled (except in the rarest of cases).  Exceptions are the bread and butter of exception handling.  The [Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) explains it well:

> An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems that a
>   reasonable application should not try to catch. Most such errors are abnormal
>   conditions.

Look at a few of the subclasses of `Error`, taking some of their JavaDoc comments:

- `AnnotationFormatError` - Thrown when the annotation parser attempts to read an annotation from a class file and determines that the annotation is malformed.
- `AssertionError` - Thrown to indicate that an assertion has failed.
- `LinkageError` - Subclasses of LinkageError indicate that a class has some dependency on another class; however, the latter class has incompatibly changed after the compilation of the former class.
- `VirtualMachineError` - Thrown to indicate that the Java Virtual Machine is broken or has run out of resources necessary for it to continue operating.

There are really three important subcategories of `Throwable`:

- `Error` - Something severe enough has gone wrong the most applications should crash rather than try to handle the problem,
- Unchecked Exception (aka `RuntimeException`) - Very often a programming error such as a `NullPointerException` or an illegal argument.  Applications can sometimes handle or recover from this `Throwable` category -- or at least catch it at the Thread's `run()` method, log the complaint, and continue running.
- Checked Exception (aka Everything else) - Applications are expected to be able to catch and meaningfully do something with the rest, such as `FileNotFoundException` and `TimeoutException`...

Comment: Oracle says that `Unchecked exceptions != RuntimeExceptions` ; `Unchecked exceptions = RuntimeExceptions + Errors`. I know that it raises the question: *Is error an exception?*, but this is what they write. Here is just one of those examples: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html .

Comment: The unanswered question is **how is RuntimeException and Error different in essence?** Both are unchecked and equal in every other way.

Answer (score 51):

This [slide showing Java's exception hierarchy](https://speakerdeck.com/gousiosg/exception-handling-bug-hazards-on-android?slide=8) by [@georgios-gousios](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51681/georgios-gousios) concisely explains the differences between Errors and Exceptions in Java.

[image: Java Exception Hierarchy]

Comment: I would love to see someone recovering from a NullPointerException :D:D:D

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia It can be and it even has sense (the other question is if it is good). Normally you check if the object exists and after that call the method or use the field. But you can instead of checking for existence try catching NPE instead. And log a message about it and go on, for example.

Comment: @Gangnus: makes no sense. Remember that an exception skips parts of code and is a way to report errors, not normal operations

Answer (score 20):

Errors tend to signal the end of your application as you know it.  It typically cannot be recovered from and should cause your VM to exit.  Catching them should not be done except to possibly log or display and appropriate message before exiting.

**Example: 
OutOfMemoryError** - Not much you can do as your program can no longer run.

Exceptions are often recoverable and even when not, they generally just mean an attempted operation failed, but your program can still carry on.

**Example:
IllegalArgumentException** - Passed invalid data to a method so that method call failed, but it does not affect future operations.

These are simplistic examples, and there is another wealth of information on just Exceptions alone.

Comment: Look https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-how-to-solve-illegal-argument-exception/ as example. IllegalArgumentException is Runtime exception, not Error. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html

Answer (score 15):

**[Errors](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Error.java) -**

1. `Error`s in java are of type `java.lang.Error`.
2. All errors in java are unchecked type.
3. `Error`s happen at run time. They will not be known to compiler.
4. It is impossible to recover from errors.
5. `Error`s are mostly caused by the environment in which application is running.
6. **Examples :** `java.lang.StackOverflowError`, `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`

**[Exceptions](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Exception.java) -**

1. `Exception`s in java are of type `java.lang.Exception`.
2. `Exception`s include both checked as well as unchecked type.
3. Checked exceptions are known to compiler where as unchecked exceptions are not known to compiler because they occur at run time.
4. You can recover from exceptions by handling them through `try-catch` blocks.
5. `Exception`s are mainly caused by the application itself.
6. **Examples :** Checked Exceptions : `SQLException`, `IOException` 
   Unchecked Exceptions : `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`, `ClassCastException`, `NullPointerException`

further reading : http://javaconceptoftheday.com/difference-between-error-vs-exception-in-java/
[image: http://javaconceptoftheday.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/ErrorVsException.png]

Answer (score 9):

Sun [puts it best](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html):

> An Error is a subclass of Throwable
>   that indicates serious problems that a
>   reasonable application should not try
>   to catch.

Answer (score 5):

The description of the `Error` class is quite clear:

> An `Error` is a subclass of `Throwable`
>   that indicates serious problems that a
>   reasonable application should not try
>   to catch. Most such errors are
>   abnormal conditions. The `ThreadDeath`
>   error, though a "normal" condition, is
>   also a subclass of `Error` because most
>   applications should not try to catch
>   it.
>
> A method is not required to declare in
>   its throws clause any subclasses of
>   `Error` that might be thrown during the
>   execution of the method but not
>   caught, since these errors are
>   abnormal conditions that should never
>   occur.

Cited from Java's own [documentation of the class `Error`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html).

In short, you should not catch `Error`s, except you have a good reason to do so. (For example to prevent your implementation of web server to crash if a servlet runs out of memory or something like that.)

An `Exception`, on the other hand, is just a normal exception as in any other modern language. You will find a detailed description in the Java API documentation or any online or offline resource.

Answer (score 3):

There is several similarities and differences between classes `java.lang.Exception` and `java.lang.Error`.

**Similarities:**

- First - both classes extends `java.lang.Throwable` and as a result
  inherits many of the methods which are common to be used when dealing
  with errors such as: `getMessage`, `getStackTrace`, `printStackTrace` and
  so on.
- Second, as being subclasses of `java.lang.Throwable` they both inherit
  following properties:

  - Throwable itself and any of its subclasses (including `java.lang.Error`) can be declared in method exceptions list using `throws` keyword. Such declaration required only for `java.lang.Exception` and subclasses, for `java.lang.Throwable`, `java.lang.Error` and `java.lang.RuntimeException` and their subclasses it is optional.
  - Only `java.lang.Throwable` and subclasses allowed to be used in the `catch` clause.
  - Only `java.lang.Throwable` and subclasses can be used with keyword - `throw`.

The conclusion from this property is following both `java.lang.Error` and `java.lang.Exception` can be declared in the method header, can be in `catch` clause, can be used with keyword `throw`.

**Differences:**

- First - conceptual difference: `java.lang.Error` designed to be
  thrown by the JVM and indicate serious problems and intended to stop
  program execution instead of being caught(but it is possible as for
  any other `java.lang.Throwable` successor).

  A passage from [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) description about `java.lang.Error`:

  > ...indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should
  >   not try to catch.

  In opposite `java.lang.Exception` designed to represent errors that
  expected and can be handled by a programmer without terminating
  program execution.

  A passage from [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) description about `java.lang.Exception`:

  > ...indicates conditions that a reasonable application might want to
  >   catch.
- The second difference between `java.lang.Error` and `java.lang.Exception` that first considered to be a **unchecked** exception for compile-time exception checking. As the result code throwing `java.lang.Error` or its subclasses don't require to declare this error in the method header. While throwing `java.lang.Exception` required declaration in the method header.

Throwable and its successor class diagram (properties and methods are omitted).
[image]

Answer (score 1):

IMO an error is something that can cause your application to fail and should not be handled.  An exception is something that can cause unpredictable results, but can be recovered from.

Example:

If a program has run out of memory it is an error as the application cannot continue.  However, if a program accepts an incorrect input type it is an exception as the program can handle it and redirect to receive the correct input type.

Answer (score 1):

Errors are mainly caused by the environment in which application is running. For example, OutOfMemoryError occurs when JVM runs out of memory or StackOverflowError occurs when stack overflows.

Exceptions are mainly caused by the application itself. For example, NullPointerException occurs when an application tries to access null object or ClassCastException occurs when an application tries to cast incompatible class types.

Source : [Difference Between Error Vs Exception In Java](http://javaconceptoftheday.com/difference-between-error-vs-exception-in-java/)

Comment: "Errors are mainly caused by the environment in which application is running" and "Exceptions are mainly caused by the application itself" perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty good summary from Java API what an Error and Exception represents:

> An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch. Most such errors are abnormal conditions. The ThreadDeath error, though a "normal" condition, is also a subclass of Error because most applications should not try to catch it.
>
> A method is not required to declare in
>   its throws clause any subclasses of
>   Error that might be thrown during the
>   execution of the method but not
>   caught, since these errors are
>   abnormal conditions that should never
>   occur.

OTOH, for Exceptions, Java API says:

> The class Exception and its subclasses are a form of Throwable that indicates conditions that a reasonable application might want to catch.

Answer (score 0):

Errors are caused by the environment where your application or program runs. Most times, you may not recover from it as this ends your application or program. Javadoc advised that you shouldn't bother catching such errors since the environment e.g. JVM, on such errors is going to quit anyway.

Examples:
`VirtualMachineError` - Thrown to indicate that the Java Virtual Machine is broken or has run out of resources necessary for it to continue operating.
`OutOfMemoryError` occurs when JVM runs out of memory or 
`StackOverflowError` occurs when stack runs over.

Exceptions are caused by your application or program itself; maybe due to your own mistake. Most times you can recover from it and your application would still continue to run. You are advised to catch such errors to prevent abnormal termination of your application or program and/or to be able to customize the exception message so the users see a nicely formatted message instead of the default ugly exception messages scattered all over the place.

Examples:
`NullPointerException` occurs when an application tries to access null object. or
Trying to access an array with a non-existing index or calling a function with wrong data or parameters.