# Ruby Exception or Error?

Tags: ruby, exception, class, hierarchy

I have noticed that in the Ruby exception hierarchy, there are "errors" such as ArgumentError and there are "exceptions" such as SignalException. Is there a certain practise of naming exceptions? thanks in advance, ell.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912334/differences-betweeen-exception-and-error has a good description of the differences between exceptions and errors, albeit for a language other than ruby.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared things up a bit!

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I think that reference is misleading in the case of Ruby. Ruby's error/exception hierarchy is designed such that classes representing situations requiring handling are extremely likely to be subclasses of StandardError or RuntimeError and _should_ have `Error` in their names.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looking at [the list of Ruby exceptions](http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html#34), `SignalException` is the only one that is named `*Exception`; everything else is an `XXXError` (except for `SystemExit` and `fatal`).  If anything, the practice is to name your exception `FooError`.  I'm having trouble finding any specific reason why `SignalException` isn't named `SignalError`.

Comment: I would second that. Another question, since everything we _should_ be rescuing is inherited from `StandardError`, would it make sense to use `rescue StandardError => error` instead of `rescue StandardError => exception`? I've always used `exception` but this answer gave me pause now.

Comment: Yes, I think it _would_ make sense to call it `error`.

Answer (score 5):

The convention is `Module::#{Type}Error` for anything caused by your application (e.g. http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/3/7/raising-the-right-exception). Exception handling in Ruby isn't stratified the same way as in Java since the exception model is different at the language level.

From what I've seen, the conventions are adhered to a little more loosely for C/FFI/JNA extensions.