# Extend Error or runtimeException while creating custom unchecked exception

Tags: java, exception, error-handling

`Error` and `RuntimeException` both are the unchecked exception.
Which one should I extend while creating custom unchecked exception? Though both are logically different , but if my only purpose of extending them is to create unchecked exception , does it really matters which one i extend ? Also I am not sure but performance vice both should be same , i guess.

P.S. I have idea about difference between `Error` and `Exception`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912334/differences-betweeen-exception-and-error

Comment: @pingw33n : dude , As I said, I know these.

Comment: *"I have idea about difference between Error and Exception."* - If you **really** understand the difference, the answer to your Question is self evident.

Answer (score 7):

Extend `RuntimeException`. `Error` is generally used only internally by the JVM, to signal situations (e.g. out of memory) from which you can not recover.

See the [Java Language specification (11.1)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1) for more details