# Why do we need Error class?

Tags: java, exception

We have `Throwable` class which is the base class for `Error` class (for **unrecoverable** errors) and `Exception` class(for **recoverable** errors)

So,

**1>** we **can** `throw` an object that implement `error` class.(Although it doesn't make sense to implement `Error` class because we have `Exception` class to do the same thing..)

**2>** Java doesn't recommend to catch `Error` object..

---

So what is the need of `Error` object then? Cant the compiler implement it internally? Isn't it a mistake?

Comment: You can throw errors. You just shouldn't.

Comment: While you rarely `catch` them, you would like to have some cleanup `finally` done anyway.

Comment: The real distinction here is between checked exceptions and unchecked exceptions. `Error` and `RuntimeException`, along with all their subclasses, are unchecked exceptions -- no need to declare them in `throw`, shouldn't `catch`.

Comment: Also see my answer, maybe it will clarify things for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differences betweeen Exception and Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912334/differences-betweeen-exception-and-error)

Comment: @ataylor my question was why doesnt java hide the implementation of `error`..just as `c#` has only onle class `Exception`...i didnt asked not difference between

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Technically, the distinction is not really made between "unrecoverable error" and "recoverable error", but between checked exceptions and unchecked exceptions. Java *does* distinguish between them as follows:

- you *must* declare a checked exception in your `throws` clause; if using a method which throws a checked exception in a `try` block, you must either `catch` said exception or add this exception to your method's `throws` clause;
- you *may* declare an unchecked exception in your `throws` clause (not recommended); if using a method which throws an unchecked exception in a `try` block, you *may* `catch` that exception or add this exception to your method's `throws` clause (not recommended either).

What is certainly not recommended, unless you *really* know what you are doing, is to "swallow" any kind of unchecked exception (ie, `catch` it with an empty block).

`Exception` is the base checked exception class; `Error` and `RuntimeException` are both unchecked exceptions, and so are all their subclasses. You will note that all three classes extend `Throwable`, and the javadoc for `Throwable` states that:

> For the purposes of compile-time checking of exceptions, Throwable and
>   any  subclass of Throwable that is not also a subclass of either
>   RuntimeException or Error are regarded as checked exceptions.

Classical examples of (in)famous unchecked exceptions:

- `OutOfMemoryError` (extends `Error`);
- `StackOverflowError` (extends `Error`);
- `NullPointerException` (extends `RuntimeException`);
- `IllegalArgumentException` (extends `RuntimeException`);
- etc etc.

The only real difference between `Error` and `RuntimeException` is their estimated severity level, and is a "semantic" difference, not a technical difference: ultimately, both behave the same. Some IDEs (Intellij IDEA comes to mind) will also yell at you if you catch an `Error` but do not rethrow it.

Comment: definitive reference..thx..i guess we can `catch` an `error` to keep log of unrecoverable errors..that is the only reason to catch `error` object i guess

Comment: Well, while I don't know how log systems work internally, they always seem to log exceptions which you don't log explicitly... To be honest I have never understood how they did it, I just "let that happen" :p

Answer (score 7):

You certainly **can** throw objects that extend (not implement) the `Error` class.

As you said, `Error` exists for unrecoverable errors. The most extensive use is within the JVM itself which uses subclasses of `Error` for things it can't recover from and doesn't expect you to be able to recover from - such as running out of memory.

Comment: This seems to be the only/closest answer to the question in the heading: 'Why do we need Error class?' I personally can never see a reason to implement it in my own code, but when the JVM returns one of these after a catastrophic occurrence, I can look up the Java Documentation for the appropriate Error subclass. I might not put them in code, but they are definitely useful and I am glad they are exposed.

Answer (score 5):

javadoc for error says

> An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems
>   that a reasonable application should not try to catch. Most such
>   errors are abnormal conditions.

whereas for Exception, the javadoc says

> The class Exception and its subclasses are a form of Throwable that
>   indicates conditions that a reasonable application might want to
>   catch.

**Some Differences**

1. Error is not meant to be caught, even if you catch it you can not recover from it. For example during **OutOfMemoryError**, if you catch it you will get it again because GC may not be able to free memory in first place. On the other hand Exception can be caught and handled properly.
2. Error are often fatal in nature and recovery from Error is not possible which is different in case of Exception which may not be fatal in all cases.
   Difference between Error and Exception in Java
3. Unlike Error, Exception is generally divided into two categories e.g. checked and unchecked Exceptions. Checked Exception has special place in Java programming language and require a mandatory try catch finally code block to handle it. On the other hand Unchecked Exception, which are subclass of RuntimeException mostly represent programming errors. Most common example of unchecked exception is NullPointerException in Java.
4. Similar to unchecked Exception, Error in Java are also unchecked. Compiler will not throw compile time error if it doesn't see Error handled with try catch or finally block. In fact handling Error is not a good Idea because recovery from Error is mostly not possible.

That's all on difference between Error and Exception in Java. key point to remember is that Error are fatal in nature and recovery may not be possible, on the other hand by carefully handling Exception you can make your code more robust and guard against different scenarios.

Look at a few of the subclasses of Error, taking from their respective javadoc:

> AnnotationFormatError - Thrown when the annotation parser attempts to
>   read an annotation from a class file and determines that the
>   annotation is malformed.
>
> AssertionError - Thrown to indicate that an assertion has failed.
>
> LinkageError - Subclasses of LinkageError indicate that a class has
>   some dependency on another class; however, the latter class has
>   incompatibly changed after the compilation of the former class.
>
> VirtualMachineError - Thrown to indicate that the Java Virtual Machine
>   is broken or has run out of resources necessary for it to continue
>   operating.

Answer (score 3):

From [the Error documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html):

> An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch.

and [the Exception documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html):

> The class Exception and its subclasses are a form of Throwable that indicates conditions that a reasonable application might want to catch.

I think this makes the distinction clear. Note also that both inherit from throwable and so can both be thrown.

Comment: yes..i pointed out the same thing in my question..this is the reason why i want to know if `error` class is useless..

Comment: Personally I don't see it as a useful distinction, but then, I'm a C# programmer where this convention does not exist, and neither does the `throws` contract. However, this is a subjective question, and I don't think you'll get an answer ultimately.