# When would we directly extend java.lang.Error?

Tags: java

In what use case would a custom `Error` class be required?

I know there are many specialised subclasses of Error in Java API (e.g. `LinkageError`, `ServiceConfigurationError`, `ThreadDeath`, `VirtualMachineError`) but I think these are only required by the Java runtime and mostly are not required in the application code of a Java developer.

I am well aware about creating custom `Exception` classes and their usage scenarios, but I'm not sure about `Error`.

Comment: You can find info here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196820/why-do-we-need-error-class]

Answer (score 2):

As the documentation describes:

> An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch.

Exceptions, on the other hand, are designed to be caught.  Unchecked `RuntimeException`s should be caught judiciously (because the code that raised it is indicating something unexpected happened) but the JVM itself is in no danger; if the caller believes it can recover from the `RuntimeException`, it's safe to do so.

Therefore if there is something in your program that *no* "reasonable application" would ever want to handle, an `Error` is appropriate.  This is very, very rare however.

Look at some of the existing subclasses, like `LinkageError` and `VirtualMachineError` and it's subclasses `InternalError`, `OutOfMemoryError`, `StackOverflowError`, and `UnknownError` - these are raised when the JVM has failed and there's nothing it can do to recover, not even let the user try to handle it.

If you have an additional case where your code could fail catastrophically and you want to similarly force the application to terminate, use an `Error` (probably an `AssertionError`).  The vast majority of the time, however, a `RuntimeException` of some sort is sufficient, as it allows a user to at least try to correct the problem while the program is running.