# Catching Exception in java to make application continue its execution

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, throwable

This is what i have right now, this method open's a connection with http url,

```
public static void setCameraList(String list) {
        URL calculator;
        try {   
    String url = "http://example.com/index.php?cameraList=" +URLEncoder.encode(list, "ISO-8859-1");
            calculator = new URL(url);
            URLConnection calcConnection = calculator.openConnection();
             BufferedReader streamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(calcConnection.getInputStream()));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This work's fine, but sometimes when url is unreachable or return's some error code this `method` seem's to crash full app.

What i am curious about is, Why this method fails to catch `Exception` ?

Also,  If i add this :

```
            catch(Throwable th){

            }
```

Will this `method` `catch` every possible `error/exception` related to what operation's i perform inside it ?

Comment: Are you sure it fails here?

Comment: if it is a runtime exception then you need to catch a runtime exception exlicitly...

Comment: yes i am sure.. i tested by making  that url respond with an error..

Comment: If you want to catch everything, catch Throwable.

Comment: @user2220766 are you talking about http error codes???

Comment: @HotLicks That means.. if i catch `Throwable` it will be swallowed inside this method and will never be passed into it's calling method..

Comment: If you swallow, eg, an OutOfMemoryError, you're not going to get very far.  Swallowing the exception/error does not correct the errant condition.

Comment: What do you mean by "seem's to crash full app"? What does this "crash" look like?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a Java expert, but you should consider that there is a difference between exception and error. 
Did you have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912334/differences-betweeen-exception-and-error)?

May you post the stacktrace? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you add this :  `catch(Throwable th){ }` every single **exception** your method throws will be catch. In order to resolve your problem properly, you must pay atention about what type of exception is thrown when the problem you are describing happens!

Comment: As the name suggests, *anything* that can be `throw`n is by definition an instance of `Throwable` (or `null`). Catching `Throwable` will thus catch anything that can be caught at all.