# What is a Boxed Error in Scala?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

When I run my application, the browser shows

```
[ExecutionException: Boxed Error]
```

It doesn't say anything about the line number, etc.

In the console, I have the following

```
! @6elaah0c8 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/testlearn] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[ExecutionException: Boxed Error]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$17$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:326) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$17$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:324) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Boxed Error
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$.resolver(Promise.scala:52) ~[factorie-1.0.0-M4-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$.scala$concurrent$impl$Promise$$resolveTry(Promise.scala:44) ~[factorie-1.0.0-M4-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:116) ~[factorie-1.0.0-M4-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55) ~[factorie-1.0.0-M4-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:58) ~[factorie-1.0.0-M4-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:23) [factorie-1.0.0-M4-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:165) ~[factorie-1.0.0-M4-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at cc.factorie.util.TraversableExtras$class.max2ByDouble(TraversableExtras.scala:95) ~[factorie-1.0.0-M4-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at cc.factorie.package$$anon$2.max2ByDouble(package.scala:148) ~[factorie-1.0.0-M4-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at cc.factorie.optimize.SampleRankExample.accumulateExampleInto(SampleRank.scala:31) ~[factorie-1.0.0-M4-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at cc.factorie.optimize.OnlineTrainer$$anonfun$processExamples$3.apply(Trainer.scala:72) ~[factorie-1.0.0-M4-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at cc.factorie.optimize.OnlineTrainer$$anonfun$processExamples$3.apply(Trainer.scala:63) ~[factorie-1.0.0-M4-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

"Boxed Error" is Scala's response to an `Error` being thrown within a `Future`.  In Java, and hence Scala, subclasses of type `Error` have a special meaning as *Fatal* errors.  See [Differences between Exception and Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912334/differences-betweeen-exception-and-error).  In short, the javadoc says:

> An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems
>   that a reasonable application should not try to catch. Most such
>   errors are abnormal conditions.

Unlike throwing other `Throwable`s within a future, when a subclass of `Error` is thrown, the default Scala resolver will wrap up the `Error` in a `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException`, with the message string "Boxed Error", and complete your promise with a failure.

To quote the futures documentation http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html w.r.t. `Error` being thrown:

> [Error] exceptions are rethrown in the thread executing the failed
>   asynchronous computation. The rationale behind this is to prevent
>   propagation of critical and control-flow related exceptions normally
>   not handled by the client code and at the same time inform the client
>   in which future the computation failed.

If you want to do something special with the Failure, the original `Error` that was thrown can be extracted (but not in a way particularly amenable to pattern matching), by `ExecutionException#getCause()`

Comment: I'm kinda missing why anything throwable "leaks" from the Future in the first place, shouldn't be the original AssertionError just caught and future's oncomplete callback be passed a Failure(ex) ?

Comment: I see Future handling NonFatal exception, but AssertionError is actually a NonFatal exception, so it should be caught and passed as a value

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that's a `Boxed Error`, but according to your stacktrace, the root problem comes from the `factorie` lib, from the `max2Double` [method at line 95](https://code.google.com/p/factorie/source/browse/src/main/scala/cc/factorie/util/TraversableExtras.scala?name=factorie-1.0.0-M4#95).

Extract from the source code:

```
/**Returns both the maximum element and the second-to-max element */
  def max2ByDouble(extractor: A => Double): (A, A) = {
    val s1 = t.toSeq
    assert(s1.length > 1)   // <<<== HERE
    var best1 = Double.NegativeInfinity
    ...
```

It seems that your `Traversable` is empty.