# How to log the error message when OutOfMemoryError occurs

Tags: java, exception, out-of-memory

I have an OOM error(Perm Gen is full), problem is when I am logging the error message into the log file, error occurs while the classloader is loading the exception handling class.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't handle errors as your application is in abnormal state:

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html
>
> [Differences between Exception and Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912334/differences-between-exception-and-error)

This answer explains scenario where you might want to do it though:

> [Catching java.lang.OutOfMemoryError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679330/catching-java-lang-outofmemoryerror)

Comment: I've never had any problem recovering from an `OutOfMemoryError` in particular. Some allocation failed, the try block got disrupted and the program happily continues on. ... The program *would* be in an inconsistent state if the body of the try block is designed badly, that is, if some user-imposed invariants are corrupted if interrupted half-way.

Answer (score 0):

You can either throw this error to handle where you're using it or you can put a try catch block around your logic(code) and you can log the error inside the catch or finally block.

Comment: I think you need to read the Java Doc, OutOfMemoryError is not an exception!!! 
  
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html