# Why finally block exists?

Tags: try-catch-finally

In  most programming languages, there is a finally block that can be placed after try or catch block like this :

```
try {
    sensitiveFunction();
} catch (Exception e) {
    executedWhenFailed();
} finally {
    alwaysExecuted();
}
```

But we can execute the same code without finally block like that :

```
try {
    sensitiveFunction();
} catch (Exception e) {
    executedWhenFailed();
}

alwaysExecuted();
```

So, why does finally block exist? Anyone have an example that finally block is required ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even these examples aren't equivalent: if `sensitiveFunction()` throws something which doesn't extend `Exception` [but `Error` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912334/differences-between-exception-and-error), `alwaysExecuted` won't be executed without `finally` (please don't try to "fix" this by catching `Throwable`).

Or say `executedWhenFailed()` itself throws an exception: it's quite common to rethrow an exception from a `catch` block after adding some information. Again, `alwaysExecuted()` won't be executed in the second snippet.

Or suppose you have `return sensitiveFunction();` instead of just a call. Etc. etc.

Comment: Also, you don't usually catch *every* exception that might get thrown; only catch the ones you can do something about, or at least re-throw the ones you can't.

Answer (score 1):

`finally` exists so that code can always be run, without regard to if you caught the exception or not.

Sometimes you want to just use `try` and `finally` together:

```
allocate()
try: 
   do_something_with_allocated()
finally:
   deallocate()
```

In the above example, it lets you 100% confidently clean up a resource that was opened above without regard for any exceptions that may be propagating up.

Answer (score 0):

If you throw a new exception in your catch block, you will eventually (after that exception has been handled) end up in your finally block. But not in the line after your catch.

Just throw an exception in `executedWhenFailed`, in your first example `alwaysExecuted` will be executed, in the second it wil not.

Answer (score 0):

The `finally` block is executed even if there is a `return` statement in the `catch()` block.

(Example in JavaScript)

```js
function foo() {
  try {
    throw "first"
  } catch(err){
    console.log(err)
    return "third"
  } finally {
    console.log("second") // Called before return in catch block
  }
  return "Never reached"
}

console.log(foo())
```