# java errors and exceptions handling

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, try-catch

Please see below for the description of the problem.

```
try {
 //some comde may throw error/exception etc 

} catch (Exception e) {
  //do something
} catch (Error e) {   //is it possible this line may get into action? I mean is there any case Exception may not be enough? so Error needs to take over the control?
 //do something
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40225083

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences between Exception and Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912334/differences-between-exception-and-error)

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course - for example `AssertionError` is extending `Error`. To catch all exceptions you should catch `Throwable`

```
try {
    // ...
} catch(Throwable t) {
    // ...
}
```

take a look also at: [Differences between Exception and Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912334/differences-between-exception-and-error)